# My problems in the integration between spring and freemarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

Where did I go wrong? when I start `tomcat`, everything is ok, `freemarker` is working ok, but in `spring-mvc.xml` I get the error[No setter found for property `'freemarkerSettings'` in class:
'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer']

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>
```

and in my `spring-mvc.xml`

```
    <!-- Freemarker -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">10</prop>
            <prop key="defaultEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="url_escaping_charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="locale">zh_CN</prop>
            <prop key="boolean_format">true,false</prop>
            <prop key="time_format">HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="datetime_format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="date_format">yyyy-MM-dd</prop>
            <prop key="number_format">#.##</prop>
            <prop key="whitespace_stripping">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="freemarkerVariables">
        <map>
            <entry key="resources" value="/site-war/resources" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It seems that  `"templateLoaderPath"` and `"freemarkerSettings"` 'freemarkerVariables' has errors [No setter found for property 'freemarkerSettings' in class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer']
 How to fixed, oops,my English is really poor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include spring-context-support.jar. As mentioned in [this link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10233), org.springframework.ui.freemarker and a number of other packages that used to reside in spring-context.jar have moved to spring-context-support.jar in 3.2.0

Comment: I have include spring-context-support.jar by using maven

Comment: I had a wrong project ,now , I recreate a new project and problems is gone! thanks